# wcf error with metadata

Tags: c#, wcf

I am getting metadata error when I reference WCF service from console app. "Error downloading metadata from the address". Here is my service code. I appreciate any help.

```
namespace WcfService1
{
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public void test(string parm1, long parm2, Stream parm3)
        {

            string folder1 = @"C:\TEST";
            string fileName = Path.Combine(folder1, parm1);

            using (FileStream target = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {

                    const int bufferLen = 65536;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLen];
                    int count = 0;
                    while ((count = parm3.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLen)) > 0)
                    {
                        target.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                    }
            }

        }
    }
}

    namespace WcfService1
    {

        [ServiceContract]
        public interface IService1
        {
            [OperationContract]
            void test(string parm1, long parm2, Stream parm3);
        }
    }
```

Here is Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: marc_s: Please see my CONFIG.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this is due to you taking a `System.IO.Stream` as a parameter to Test. In my experience (and someone might come along and correct me here) you have two options:

1. Wrap the request in a request-object (see below).
2. Remove param1 and param2 and only use the Stream-param.

Service Interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{

        [OperationContract]
        void test(Request request);
}
```

DataContract:

```
namespace WcfService1
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Request
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Param1 { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public long Param2 { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public Stream Param3 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

You might need some additional work with using [KnownType] for subsets of Stream, but I'm quite unsure of this. The above should at least get you away from the MetaData Error you are seeing when adding the service reference.